# How to compare column from two tables?

Tags: c#, sql

Suppose I have two tables.

Table_1:

```
Prod_name  Quantity
A          15
B          5
C          17
```

Table_2:

```
Prod_name  threshold
A          7
B          6
C          8
```

How can I compare these two tables in SQL, so that particular `prod_name` is displayed if its quantity falls below threshold level from another table?

Expected output

```
Med_name  Quantity
B         5
```

Comment: You should not expect Stack Overflow to be a code-writing service.

Comment: @Milen Please do not destroy questions by editing it to unreadability.

Comment: @UweKeim I was not my intention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Note - using string to `LEFT JOIN` the tables `ON` isn't great - try to use a `Product_Code` or `ID` if you know they're the same in both tables.

Using the info that I know about your table structure though - something like this should do the trick.

```
SELECT a.Prod_name AS Med_name
     , CASE WHEN a.Quantity < b.Quantity 
            THEN a.Quantity 
            ELSE b.Quantity
  FROM ( 
         SELECT Prod_name
              , Quantity
           FROM Table_1
       ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT Prod_name
              , Quantity
           FROM Table_2
       ) b
    ON ( LOWER(a.Prod_Name) = LOWER(b.Prod_Name) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT A.Prod_name AS Med_name,A.Quantity FROM Table_1 A INNER JOIN Table_2 B ON 
    A.Prod_name=B.Prod_name WHERE A.Quantity < B.threshold
```